# Need most reliable way to push notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have an android app that uses GCM for push notifications. Lets say I need this for ambulance drivers when new calls are received. Right now there is a delay between when the server sends out the push notification and when the android device receives it, sometimes more than a minute. I've read on Stack Overflow about sending the heartbeat out, set delay_while_idle to true/false( yes I've seen both) etc...

What I need to know is if this is just how it is with GCM or if there is a way to make push notification times much more reliable. I've had suggestions of sockets, test messages etc... Because this is potentially for medical services I can't afford to have delays longer than what is absolutely necessary.
I've read that GCM notification delivery isn't guaranteed so is there a direction someone can point me to maybe do this on my own so that I can make something is guaranteed???

Comment: This is a broad question. There can be many ways to send information to server. 1. GCM 2. SMS 3. XMPP (I believe, GCM uses this under the hood). There are going to be cases when a device will be out of coverage. Also, you may start with GCM with SMS as fallback and later explore XMPP and other options, as they are significantly more difficult to use.

Answer (score 1):

GCM push notifications are not reliable.

Have a look at "**Pushy**": https://pushy.me/

They state the following on their website:

> The most reliable push notification gateway,  perfect for real-time
>   applications.
>
> Google Cloud Messaging simply doesn't cut it for time-sensitive,
>   real-time apps, due to its instability and push notification
>   throttling.
>
> Pushy works by maintaining a dedicated background socket connection
>   using the MQTT protocol, an extremely light-weight pub/sub protocol
>   that consumes very little network bandwidth and battery, which makes
>   it perfect for mobile.

You can use it for free with up to 100 devices, so you could just give it a try to see, if it fits your needs. I didn't try it.